# pecl_http extension not working

Tags: php, php-ini

I installed pecl_http extension in windows and I ran the following code:

```
<?php
$r = new HttpRequest('http://example.com/feed.rss', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$r->setOptions(array('lastmodified' => filemtime('local.rss')));
$r->addQueryData(array('category' => 3));
try {
   $r->send();
   if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
      file_put_contents('local.rss', $r->getResponseBody());
   }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
      echo $ex;
}
?>
```

I get error as below:

```
Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_services\pecl_http.php on line 3
```

This is how I installed pecl_http:

downloaded and added following lines to php.ini (thread safe vc9)

```
extension=php_raphf.dll
extension=php_propro.dll
extension=php_http.dll
```

This is what I get when I run phpinfo() function:

[image]

I am using php 5.4.22 (xampp) on windows 8.

Why am I getting this class not found error when I have the pecl extension enabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I figured out what was wrong. I installed http version 2 extension which is a complete renovation of version 1. Instead of HttpRequest class, we have http \ Client () class. I got this information from one of the comments on https://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php.
The documentation for http 2 is at http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http/. The documentation lacks example though.